# How to list all the tables from the database in Sqlite flutter?

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter

How can I return all the tables stored in my database in the form of a list in Sqlite flutter?

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/sys_tables/index.php

Comment: Hi @Shahbaz Welcome in SO, What have you tried for it.Add more info in your code to get quick response from here..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just query `sqlite_master` table:

```dart
final tables = await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM sqlite_master ORDER BY name;');
```

Comment: how to map the result to objects?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get all table names which contain in your database. You can use this method for it. this method return table names list.

```
//********* Get all tableName from Database *********//

Future<List<String>> getAllTableNames() async {
// you can use your initial name for dbClient
List<Map> maps =
    await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM sqlite_master ORDER BY name;');

List<String> tableNameList = [];
if (maps.length > 0) {
  for (int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
    try {
      tableNameList.add(maps[i]['name'].toString());
    } catch (e) {
      print('Exeption : ' + e);
    }
  }
}`return tableNameList;}
```